# System replacement technology

Tags: scalability, environment

I have some questions that I am hoping someone out there will be able to answer for me.

Our situation is that we are considering a ground up replacement for an existing system. Firstly I will describe the existing system that we have.

We are currently operating on a pure object stack. The enviroment is OO and the database is OO. We currently have 3-4 million lines of code which was developed by 2-3 people, and we currently have a development team of 6, which continues to develop. The initial development started in 1997, and we have many clients installed. The environment is 64-bit, language and database, mulit-lingual, and is UNICODE. The operatiung system we use is Windows (latest versions). We have a number of modules which are delivered via a thin client (not browser), and the bandwidth usage is very low (Operates on 64KB WAN network performance level which is still prevalent in some countries in which we operate, i.e. the infrastructure is poor). Our biggest implementation is for one of the biggest companies in the world, and the target is to deliver the functionality for 30+ countries from one system instance (one physical db) for that client, and deliver the functionality using thin client to all countries from one set of application servers (the application servers are located with the db server and perform all of the processing), the thin client deals with the interactions with the users and the display of the data and collection of the data only. The system is used by 1000s of users, on the thin client. We also have mobile and portal components also, which are developed in C#, they are a small segment of the overall system and connect using APis. There are maybe 1000 mobile application users, with a final number expected to be 5000 mobile users. Within the system there will be 500000-1000000 vendors, with each vendor expected to have at least two transactions every single day.

The DB itself is partitioned, and replicated to a number of locations in real time. The final size of the DB when implementation is complete is expected to be in the 2TB range, and the current system will deal with that, no problem. The way the replication works is that there are mutiple replicated enviroments on hot-standy, i,e. all application servers and API servers are replicated. Our largest client routinely (once per month) performs scheduled windows updates, and when this occurs the primary environments are automatically rolled over to the secondaries, so the system remains available all of the time. In subsequent months, the system is rolled back to the primaries, this transition is very fast, i.e. real time.

At our largest client, the system was installed in 2014, and since that time it has not experienced any outage, except for planned outages because of server maintenace of whateveer in that time period, i.e. it has not crashed or faulted in the first three years of operation. For the purposes of providing updates and enhanced functionality to the target organisation or specifically one of their subsiduries in the countries in which they operate we are able to make changes to the system, via the loading of functional updates on-line. This is a very important component of my question, as for many years we have been able to update at one central location and have the new functionality immeadiately available to all users in all countries whilst they are continuosly using the application. This is without change to any .EXE or .DLL or whatever files that the end user is operating. This is a huge advantage for us currently, as many of the organisations we provide services to do NOT allow any change to EXE or DLL files on end user devices, and there is generally some approval process which takes some days and requires manual intervention by the users to make this process happen.

For further information, we have a support team of 6 providing support services to all of our clients in all of these countries, we operate three shifts of 2 people to provide these services. So this should give you some background to the stability of the system and the level of support we provide. Our service level is described as outstanding. We do have of course SLA agreements in place and we have not violated any SLA term ever.

So, now for my question. What technology would people choose to replace such a system, and how many people would it take to replace ? It has been recommended to me that C# and SQL server be used to replace this, and that it would take a couple of good people a year or two to re-develop from the ground up (we have all of the functional specifications from the last 20 years to work from). However, without having in depth knowledge of this technology stack I am quite concerned about the time period (I think it is very optimistic), I am concerned about the scaleability of the SQL server, and most importantly I am deeply concerned that we will loose this advantage that we have enjoyed that allows us to change the functionality of the current system via updates online without effecting logged on users. I am told that this sort of thing is just not possible in C# and if we have to provide an update to fix a bug, or provide new functionality then all users will have to replace the effected EXE and DLL files, i.e. all of them, 1000s of users would have to do this each and every time we update. This would be done automatically via a process called OneClick, but I am assuming if there is a company policy within our client environment that EXE changes are not allowed, then OneClick will not be viable. I am told if we took a browser approach to the new development then any updates would be server side (which is better), but, would still require an outage to apply updates.

Finally, more information on the online updates that are now possible. Currently all of the systems are replicated for disaster recovery and 100% uptime during update purposes. When we currently update our systems (at one central location) those logical updates are automatically applied at all replicated systems also without user intervention. Another concern that I have is that as well as the problem we face with updating multiple locations with the same update, which it seems is a requirement in C# or so I am being told, we will also have all of the replicated systems to update manually as well. As you can see our support team is small, so I am worried about a future blowout in maintenance resources required to maintain all of this, and then the cost in terms of times fixing mistakes that may creep in with all these additional tasks that may be required to perform the same exercise that we currently do only once.

Finally, a final peice of information on how we currently do updates. If the update is structural in nature, i.e. changes the physical structure of the database, then an outage is required, a full system down outage. When we apply the update the structural change is made, and this is automatically replicated across all secondary (standby enviroments). The users are not effected in terms of the software for the thin client or browsers. They simply log back on after the outage is complete. We currently have a window at a set time, once per month to perform these updates, however, it is rarely required. Once per week, we have a window for functional changes to be applied, and these are appled on line whilst the users are all on line performing their daily and periodic tasks.

So, if anyone out there can give me some insight into what technologies are available for such a system replacement or whether C# and SQL server can provide the necessary services and performance we actually need, i.e. I would be particularly interested to know whether in fact C# applications can be updated in real time, then that would be fantastic. We are obviously in the very early stages of this process in terms of how this should be done, so any information you can provide would be greatly appreciated and will save many hours of research.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This doesn't look like a bad question, but it also doesn't look appropriate for the site. This is extremely broad, with many small parts, and while related to programming, isn't really a programming question. A discussion site meant for broad questions would probably be a better fit. Look into Reddit and Google+.

Comment: @iehrlich this question is a  poor fit over there for the same reasons as it is here. Please abstain of recommending sites your not familiar with. See also: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Answer (score 1):

From the basic requirements you describe, my first thought is that you should probably adopt a full Web-based solution for your system, that way all updates can be done centrally without too much negative effect on your client access.

But if I understand correctly your question, one aspect you're requiring is to have executable code ready at the client-side (so a pure Web-solution won't work).

In that case, something that can quickly & easily update at the client side is needed.

We've been using the node.js and MongoDB stack for a few years now, there are some quite interesting effects of using pure scripts for your business logic: besides being easy to develop, the scripts themselves, when designed with certain guidelines, can perform "hot reload" on the fly to update your business logic. So this is what I'd recommend trying / looking at.

Efficiency of node.js and the flexibility provided by NoSQL DB such as MongoDB is well described in many places if you do a simple Google search.